# jqgrid autorefresh subgrid problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

Currently I use this code for refreshing the grid:

```
setInterval(function(){  jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid"); },10000);
```

It works well. But I need a solution for expanded subgrids. When the grid refreshed the expanded subgrids are closing.

Is there any way to refresh the grid without close the expanded subgrids?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I struggled with the same thing so I thought I'd share what I did.  Eonasdan's answer is right on.  In my case I added code to the subGridRowExpanded and subGridRowCollapsed events to store the row ID of the row which have been expanded (I only allowed one row to be expanded at a time, but you could use a collection as well).  Then I added code to the loadComplete event for the table to re-open the row that collapsed after the postback.  That part is all obvious, but here are the two kickers:
1. Re-expanding the subgrid doesn't cause its data to be persisted for some reason.  So I had to go back to the server to get it.  I did that by resubmitting the subgrid row (which has an id of the grid an underscore and the rowid).
2. For some reason you have to use a timer and expand the subgrid after a delay (even 1ms seems to work).  It is like you can't expand the grid during the loadComplete event itself, but if you wait a tick then it works fine.

So like this:

```
var expandSubGrid = function(){

    $('#grid').jqGrid('expandSubGridRow', expandedRowID);
    $('#grid_' + expandedRowID).trigger('reloadGrid');
};


//the loadComplete event handler which was wired up when I created the grid
var grid_loadComplete = function () {
    //expand the subgrid
    window.setTimeout(expandSubGrid, 1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like [their demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/hierarchy/simple_subgrid/default.php) is changing the TR class from sgcollapsed to sgexpanded. I would think you could keep an array of TRs that are open before the refresh and re-open them after.

I know very little about jqGrid, but I thought I would post this as it seemed to point you in the right direction from the chat.